# Set my Backbone/Requirejs Application to independant plugin reusable

Tags: plugins, backbone.js, requirejs

I developped an application with `Backbone`
In order to avoid multiple js file declaration in index.html I used `RequireJS` to load js files.
Everything works fine.
My application looks like this.

index.html

```
<body>
<div id="#plugin-container"></div>
<script data-main="my-plugin" src="assets/js/require.js"></script>   
</body>
```

my-plugin.js

```
define([
'src/app'
], function(app){
    app.init(); 
});
```

app.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'src/models/main'
], function($, _, Backbone, Main){

   var init = function () {....}
});
```

Everyting works fine, but now I would like to make it a plugin, that you could use in all html project (like a `jQuery` plugin). And I don't how to proceed... The best final use could looks like :

newproject.html

```
<div id="#plugin-container"></div>
<!-- Just load plugin. Do nothing. -->
<script data-main="my-plugin" src="assets/js/require.js"></script>
<script>
     // Just an example that I would do but is sure not working....
     myPlugin.init({
         param1: true,
         param2: '/url',
         onSubmitSomething : myMethod
     })
</script>
</body>
```

my-plugin.js

```
define([
'src/app'
], function(app){
    var myPlugin = app;
    return myPlugin;
});
```

My question : How to get instance of my application after requirejs load (`myPlugin`) and launch his methods in html file (like in code above) ?
Maybe it's not a good way... 
Thx.

**Update**

I have try something.
Add in `my-plugin.js` my main app model to the window object like this :

```
// Loading main application file
define([
'src/app'
], function(app){

    global = window;
    global.myPlugin = app;

});
```

And when I try to launch `myPlugin.init()` in my html file `myPlugin` is not again accessible :

```
<script data-main="mvo-thumbnail-plugin" src="assets/js/require.js"></script>

<script>
    // Not working...
    myPlugin.init({
       "wrapper" : $("#thumbnailsManager"),
       "url_images" : "assets/",
    })
</script>
```

But when I use one setTimeout to wait requireJS initiliazation it works fine :

```
<script data-main="mvo-thumbnail-plugin" src="assets/js/require.js"></script>

<script>
    // If I wait 500ms requireJS has done and my window.myPlugin 
    // object is available
    setTimeout(function(){
        myPlugin.init({
            "wrapper" : $("#thumbnailsManager"),
            "url_images" : "assets/"
        })
    },500)
</script>
```

It's not a real solution for me. But I have maybe a new way of reflexion...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar but more advanced. Though, with your code its not pretty clear what kind of plugin you want to build or integrate to another application.

I suggest you to inclue the `my-plugin.js` file in the project directory. Then include the file path in `app.js` or `config.js` or whatever main configuration file you are using, just include.

Only thing you need to work on is making a custom model and views of it. Do keep in mind if you need some values from remote server as Collection (if not then Collection is not necessary). Then create an instance of HTML which runs your plugin.

Call a `<div>` method in the targeted source you want to include plugin and use `render` method wisely to fetch the code.

If you can specify more code, I can suggest you more accordingly.

Comment: Then specify which file you want to include and where you find it difficult?

Comment: I need to control the main model (src/models/main) : launch init() method with my own parameters like in app.js, for example.

Comment: In second time I will need to listen some events like fileIsUploaded, thumbnailsCropped, ...

Comment: For this two steps I need to get the main instance of my plugin (views/main.js or models/main.js). Now I declare a main variable in my app.js file who contains my main model but I don't know how to make this variable accessible into my html file. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution :
I don't use the automatic main js initialization by RequireJS
I replaced :

```
<script data-main="mvo-thumbnail-plugin" src="assets/js/require.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="assets/js/require.js"></script>
<script src="mvo-thumbnail-plugin.js"></script>
```

And I used the require function in my main plugin file (`mvo-thumbnail-plugin.js`) like this

```
(function (global) {
   global.myPlugin = global.myPlugin || {};

   myPlugin.init = init;

   function init(arr) {

    // paths and dependencies list
       require.config({
         shim: {
            .....
         },
         paths: {
            .....
         }
       });

    // Main require function
       require([
                'jquery',
                'underscore',
                'backbone',
                'src/models/main'
               ], function($, _, Backbone, Main){

                    app = new Main(arr);

       });
  }

}(window));
```

Then I can initialize my plugin with

```
<script>
  myPlugin.init({ .... });
</script>
```